# How to search an array from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I want to add some tags in a single column to a MySQL database, and I want to query that field for my search functionality, but I don't know how to do it. Either I can store multiple data in MySQL table as an array or as a JSON object. What would be the best for a query?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Store data in mysql table in json format if you are not applying any conditions on that data.

Comment: Never store "multiple data". By definition, relational DB is intended to structure your data into relations. Thus - your answer is: store your data in the separate linked table.

Comment: i have a product table where there is an tags column ,in tags i am storing product tags as array format using MySQL long-text data format . i am able to query it using unserialize. so my question is is this process is flexible for use. right now i did not found any limitation but i dont know if i found some while scale my search funtionality